# PostgreSQL - Difference between Current Date and a Date from Database

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm trying to make a SELECT query which will compare current time with time at database. For example in database there is a record '2018-02-07 12:00:00' and I wanna compare it to current time. If current time is '2018-02-07 11:00:00', record '2018-02-07 12:00:00' should be visible in results. It should compare two dates and shows only those who are 1h before or after current time.'

Tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE age(current_date, event_date) < '1 hour';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date > (now() - INTERVAL '1 hour');
```

Answer (score 1):

> those that are 1h before or after current time

Wouldn't the logic look like this?

```
SELECT e.*
FROM events e
WHERE e.event_date > now() - INTERVAL '1 hour' AND
      e.event_date < now() + INTERVAL '1 hour'
```